# No data in Firebase Analytics, spotty "last 30 minutes" data

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to integrate with Firebase Analytics. I was following the guide in https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup and didn't encounter anything that would end up with an error.

However, when I launch my game it says that Firebase has been initialized and there are no obvious errors in logcat. For my test user I would eventually get an entry in "Users in last 30 minutes", but it will only be for 1 minute, even if I keep the app open for the whole duration. The next day there is no data available in the analytics, even though I have been using the app for a bit while connected to the internet. Even the "last 30 minutes" data is spotty - e.g. I just launched the game but the only event I see is "session_start", with no active users per minute. I am using Firebase Auth, and it shows my test user account there signed in via Google Play Games.[image: see report]

Anyone could suggest debugging steps?

Here is the code I use to initialize everything on my first scene, in an empty GameObject:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Extensions;

#if UNITY_ANDROID
using GooglePlayGames;
#endif

public class FirebaseInitializer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private FirebaseApp app;
    private bool firebaseInitialized;

    void Awake()
    {
        //Initialize PlayGamesPlatform
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
#endif
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        InitializeFirebaseAndStart();
        while (!firebaseInitialized)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
            print("Auth " + success);

            Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
                .LogEvent(Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.EventLogin);

            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RequestServerSideAccess(/* forceRefreshToken= */ false,
            authCode => {
                Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
                Firebase.Auth.Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.PlayGamesAuthProvider.GetCredential(authCode);
                auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
                    if (task.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                        return;
                    }

                    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
                    Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                        newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
                });
            });
        });

        Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
                .LogEvent(Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.EventAppOpen);

        yield break;
    }

    // When the app starts, check to make sure that we have
    // the required dependencies to use Firebase, and if not,
    // add them if possible.
    void InitializeFirebaseAndStart()
    {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
                firebaseInitialized = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

That object also has the DoNotDestroy script attached:

```
public class DoNotDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static DoNotDestroy _instance;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }
}
```

There are no obvious errors in logcat, and some data does go through into the realtime overview, but nothing shows up in the normal analytics view and when I do get user activity in realtime overview, it's just for single minute and sometimes missing some entries (like that session_start event without an actual user logged in)

Comment: I actually see that Analytics gets initialized twice for some reason:
`2023/01/12 19:33:28.545 31026 31205 Info firebase Firebase Analytics API Initializing
2023/01/12 19:33:28.545 31026 31205 Info firebase analytics API Initialized
2023/01/12 19:33:28.598 31026 31075 Info firebase Firebase Analytics API Initializing
2023/01/12 19:33:28.598 31026 31075 Info firebase analytics API Initialized`

Comment: The initial data logged to the Firebase console usually takes up to 48 hours to display and 3-4 hours delay for the succeeding data. You could verify your implementation by checking it in [DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#android).